# errors while compiling .Net Standard 2.0 based xamarin project

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, .net-standard-2.0

i am trying to create a new project in xamarin forms based on `.Net Standard 2.0`.

When i am compiling the project i am getting around 4k error in android build

Here is errors in xamarin.android

[image: Error in android build]

My compile sdk is the `Android Oreo`

[image]

and here are the references that i have added 
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to clean and rebuild the solution? If not work, you could try to delete the bin and obj folders and rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a new solution and load the existing source code and nuget packages after that i am able to upgrade the framework to .Net standard 2.0